# Dynamic html attribute assignment in Svelte

Tags: html, dynamic, attributes, svelte

I am using Svelte for my personal web development and have the code snippet as below:

```
           <AccordionItem open>
            <span slot="header">随机TAG</span>
            <p class="mb-2 text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400 text-sm">
              {#each tags as t}
              {#if t.tc<3}
              <span
              class="dark:text-red-600 text-gray-600 font-bold text-sm"
              ><a href="/books/tag/{t.tag}" target="_self">{t.tag}</a></span> ({t.tc}) &nbsp;  
              {:else if t.tc<6}
              <span
              class="dark:text-red-600 text-gray-600 font-bold text-base"
              ><a href="/books/tag/{t.tag}" target="_self">{t.tag}</a></span> ({t.tc}) &nbsp;  
              {:else if t.tc<10}
              <span
              class="dark:text-red-600 text-gray-600 font-bold text-lg"
              ><a href="/books/tag/{t.tag}" target="_self">{t.tag}</a></span> ({t.tc}) &nbsp;
              {:else}
              <span
              class="dark:text-yellow-600 text-red-600 font-bold text-xl"
              ><a href="/books/tag/{t.tag}" target="_self">{t.tag}</a></span> ({t.tc}) &nbsp;
              {/if}
              
              {/each}
              <span
              class="dark:text-red-600 text-gray-600 font-bold"
              ></span
            >
            </p>
          </AccordionItem>
```

The key visual effect I want to achieve here is: based on the `t.tc` count, apply different `text-??` (and even more, different colors) to the tag text display.

Now I use a bunch of `if-else if-else` block to make this happen. Is there a better way to do this?

For example, I can assign a `let textsize=??` based on `t.tc` (the count), then put into the `span` element attribute as `<span class='... {textsize}'>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a dictionary that maps the different ranges to class names and a function to determine a category/range name as you do not have concrete values. E.g.

```js
function category(count) {
  return count < 3 ? 'a' :
         count < 6 ? 'b' :
         ...;
}

const categoryClasses = {
  a: 'dark:text-red-600 text-gray-600 font-bold text-sm',
  b: 'dark:text-red-600 text-gray-600 font-bold text-base',
  // ...
}
```

(Of course the names should be chosen to be more meaningful that those.)

```html
<span class="... {categoryClasses[category(t.tc)]}" ...
```

You could also combine everything into one function and return the classes directly, the lines may get a bit lengthy if there are more classes/they are not broken up.

```js
function classesForTc(count) {
  return count < 3 ? 'dark:text-red-600 text-gray-600 font-bold text-sm' :
         count < 6 ? 'dark:text-red-600 text-gray-600 font-bold text-base' :
         // ...
}
```

```html
<span class="... {classesForTc(t.tc)}"
```

Note that you should use the class names in their entirety if a processor like Tailwind generates the CSS for them.

Comment: Thanks. I can see the improvement by doing this.